# Network .dll send strings

Tags: c#, sockets, send

I use this packet class (.dll) for my multithreaded client-server application. 
BUT I don't know how to send strings with my code - pls help:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace ServerData
{
  [Serializable]
  public class Packet
  {
    public List<string> Gdata;
    public int packetInt;
    public bool packetBool;
    public string senderID;
    public PacketType packetType;

    public Packet(PacketType type, string senderID)
    {
        Gdata = new List<string>();
        this.senderID = senderID;
        this.packetType = type;
    }

    public Packet(byte[] packetbytes)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(packetbytes);
        Packet p = (Packet)bf.Deserialize(ms);
        ms.Close();
        this.Gdata = p.Gdata;
        this.packetInt = p.packetInt;
        this.packetType = p.packetType;
        this.senderID = p.senderID;
        this.packetBool = p.packetBool;

    }

    public byte[] ToBytes()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        bf.Serialize(ms, this);
        byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
        ms.Close();
        return bytes;

    }

    public static string GetIP4Address()
    {
        IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

        foreach (IPAddress i in ips) 
        {
            if (i.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return i.ToString();
            }
        }
        return "127.0.0.1";
    }
    public static string GetIP6Address()
    {
        string macAddresses = string.Empty;

        foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                break;
            }
        }

        return macAddresses;
    }
}
public enum PacketType
{
    Registration,
    Command,
    Download,
    Inquiry,
    Reponse,
    Confirmation
}
}
```

the send function in the server/client:

```
        public void SendRegistrationPacket() // for example this send an packet from the type registration but in this moment i can "know" whats in the packet by "asking" what type it is...
    {
        Packet p = new Packet(PacketType.Registration, id);
        clientSocket.Send(p.ToBytes()); //clientSocket is the socket where the client is connected^^

    }
```

the manager for the incoming data (not reading only handling the readed data):

```
    void DataManager(Packet p)
    {
        switch (p.packetType)
        {
            case PacketType.Registration:
                listBox1.Items.Add("Got Registration Packet");
                listBox1.Items.Add("Sending Registration...");
                break;
        }
    }
```

how can i send strings and "encoding" them with these packets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class provides a `public List<string> Gdata;`. You can add any number of strings to this object, and the serializer will take care of it. So e.g. you could write

```
Packet p = new Packet(PacketType.Command, 123);
p.Gdata.Add("SomeString which I want to execute");

clientSocket.Send(p.ToBytes());
```

On the receiving end, you will deserialize the `Packet` object and use the `Gdata` field as usual.

```
byte[] received = new byte[1024]; 
int num_received = someSocket.Receive(received);
Packet decoded = new Packet(received.Take(num_received).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine("The first string in the list: " + decoded.Gdata[0]);
```